# C++ how to find area of square or rectangle with vector of coordinates

Tags: c++, vector, coordinates, area

How do I find the area of square or rectangle assuming user has entered some accurate points to form a square or rectangle.

I need to calculate the area inside the square class and rectangle class respectively.

I have 2 vector of coordinates, coordX and coordY.

My idea is when either or x or y has same value it will be a line and I can find the distance x2 but I'm not sure how to implement it in code.

```
double Square::computeArea() {

    double area;

    for (int x = 0; x < coordX.size; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < coordY.size; y++) {
            if (coordX[x] == coordY[y])
            {
                //....
            }   
        }
    }       
    return area;
}
```

This is how i populate my vector with user input

```
    Square Square;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

        cout << "Please enter x-coordinate of pt " << i << ": ";    

        cin >> x;

        Square.setXCoordinate(x);

        cout << "Please enter y-coordinate of pt " << i << ": ";    

        cin >> y;       

        Square.setYCoordinate(y);

    }
```

this is my mutator function in my class. Square inherit from ShapeTwoD

```
void ShapeTwoD::setXCoordinate(int x) {
    coordX.push_back(x);
}

void ShapeTwoD::setYCoordinate(int y) {
    coordY.push_back(y);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for square root.
Take two edges from one vertex, rotate one by 90°, take dot product.

```
double dx1 = coordX[3] - coordX[0];
double dy1 = coordY[3] - coordY[0];
double dx2 = coordX[1] - coordX[0];
double dy2 = coordY[1] - coordY[0];
double area = abs(dx1*dy2 - dy1*dx2)
```

As a bonus, this will calculate the correct area for all parallelograms, not just rectangles.

This assumes, the points are entered in clockwise or couter-clockwise order. If that's not the case, find out which point has the greatest distance to point[0] then discard it and use the other two instead of `1` and `3` above.

Comment: I assumed `coordX` and `coordY` are vectors of size 4 containing the x and y coordinates of the rectangle vertices. If that's not the case, please clarify your question.

Comment: This is cross product. Or more precisely, the magnitude of the Z component of the cross product of two vectors on the X-Y plane.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do it. @TommyYap, your question doesn't make sense to me, in the light of your OP: "assuming user has entered some accurate points to form a square or rectangle."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your coordinates are something like

```
//   3-----------2
//   |           |
//   |           |
//   0-----------1
```

Then you could do

```
#include <cmath>
double distance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
{
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(x2 - x1, 2) + std::pow(y2 - y1, 2));
}

double Square::computeArea() const
{
    double length = distance(coordX[0], coordX[1], coordY[0], coordY[1]);
    double width = distance(coordX[0], coordX[3], coordY[0], coordY[3]);
    return length * width;
}
```

This allows your rectangle to be at any arbitrary orientation, instead of x-y axis aligned. You just need to maintain a convention of the indexes of the corners, like in my example diagram.

Comment: You can also use [`std::hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) to directly compute the distance.

Comment: but i am using vector once i compile its having some iterator error.I dont think i can just use the [0] position?

Comment: @TommyYap can you edit your post to show how you populate `coordX` and `coordY`?

Comment: @Cyber when i enter (1,2) (2,2) (2,1) (1,1) and print out the value of area is 1.56251e-316 is it normal?